# Check if a variable is already defined in java

Tags: java, jsp

I need to check if a variable is already defined somewhere else in the code when getting there.

Because of includes in JSP, I sometimes get a variable defined in two spots, and java then returns an error. Using the jsp:include doesn't seem to work either.

I am looking for something in the form of an `#ifndef` of c, but not in the pre-processor (as this is java) to avoid having a duplicate local variable issue.

I cannot use `==null` or `isnull()` as sometimes, the variable won't be defined at all, not just uninitialized

Comment: That smells like really bad structure.

Comment: There's no way to achieve that reliably. This is most likely a design issue that should be fixed.

Comment: You're trying to address a symptom, not the root cause.  The root cause is that you have the same variable defined twice.  Instead of looking for a hack which would allow the problem to persist without error, fix the problem itself.

Comment: Would an undefined variable (not even declared) in your code even allow for it to compile? It's not Javascript.

Comment: it is always defined when I use it, but can sometimes be defined twice. it is indeed a structural problem. it's used in JSP pages. Each have their local variables, but inclusion share the variable with the page including it. and some pages included sometimes are included by a page declaring it, sometismes not. so it need to re-declare it only if the page incluing it didn't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a magic trick that will solve your issue, the only thing that could be done is to apply a naming convention in your jsp files especially those which are meant to be included. You can for example add a prefix to the name of your variables, assuming that your file is `myfolder/foo.jsp` and your variable is `bar`, you can rename it to `myfolder_foo_jsp_bar` this way you won't have any naming collision anymore.

Comment: this would work. it's Tedious, as this variable is called a lot and having a generic named alowed me to use copy-paste, but their is no effortless solution for this I guess